# How to access to subfolders in vue

Tags: vue.js

I have below folders

```
src
  -common
    -> test.js
  -views
    ->test
      -1.vue
```

I need to call common folder in `1.vue`.

I have tried below script, but its not working.

```
import { common } from '../common'
```

Is there any suggestion on how can I call common folder from `1.vue`?

Comment: Do you mean to import test.js inside common?

Comment: @DanielRichter Yes. I want to import test.js inside 1.vue file

Answer (score 2):

If test.js is a default export then:

```
import Test from '../../common/test';
```

If it's a named export then:

```
import { Test } from '../../common/test';
```